# Get last cost for each row

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
    materials:
      int id
     text title

   costs:
     int id
     int material_id
     int cost
datetime created_at
```

data:

```
    materials:
1 Wood
2 Steel
3 ...

costs:
1,1,200,2015-07-02
2,1,205,2015-07-03
3,1,210,2015-07-04
```

I want to get materials with last costs.
like this:

```
id title cost
1  Wood  210
```

i try this:

```
select materials.id, title, cost from materials 
left join (
  select * from costs
  order by costs.id DESC
) as costs on costs.material_id = materials.id
group by materials.id
```

and this:

```
select materials.id, materials.title, c1.cost from costs c1
    join (select material_id, max(id) as id from costs group by material_id) AS c2
        on c1.id = c2.id
left join materials on materials.id = c1.material_id
```

but cost sometimes(!) was incorrect.

this return correct cost for one value:

```
    select cost, material_id
  from costs
    where material_id = 2
      order by id DESC
        limit 1
```

now i just get list of materials and get costs in php foreach loop (+1 query for each row)

help me please!

Comment: I don't think this is definitively answerable from the description and scant data set provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.id, m.title, c1.cost 
from materials m
join costs c1 on c1.material_id = m.id
join 
(
  select material_id, max(created_at) as dt
  from costs
  group by material_id
) c2 on c2.material_id = m.id and c2.dt = c1.created_at
```

Comment: thanks for fast answer! your query return duplicates by costs. adding "gropup by m.id" will return first cost. i.e. 1, wood, 200.